# Server sent event in Laravel 5 throwing an error "EventSource's response has a MIME type..."

Tags: laravel-5, server-sent-events

I am writing a code to show notifications but it is encountering an error. My code is as follows:

```
 function notify() {
        $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function() {

        while (true) {
            $notification = Notification::where('user_ID', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

                echo 'data: ' . json_encode($notification) . "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();

            sleep(3);

        }
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    return $response;
}
```

and in view I have added JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var es = new EventSource("<?php echo action('NotificationController@notify'); ?>");
    es.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        arr = JSON.parse(e.data);

           //apply some effect on change, like blinking the color of modified cell...
       // }
    }, false);
```

The error is :

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

How can I solve it? I am writing this code from a tutorial [server-sent-events-example-laravel](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/).

Comment: I have the same problem as you. When you wrap the while loop inside a function on the server side SSE doesn't work. I am still looking and searching why wrapping the loop inside a function it doesn't work when it should be working normally...

Comment: Check out if commenting function() notify and execute the code in procedural mode works for you....

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

Controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

public function notify(){

    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() {
      while(true) {
          echo 'data: ' . 'Hello' . "\n\n";
          ob_flush();
          flush();
          sleep(3);
        }
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
    $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
    return $response;
}
```

And Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');

    return $response;
}
```